# Shrink contour to fit inside original

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, contour

I have a contour with 4 points that form a parallelogram like shape, and I want to shrink the contour points and draw it inside a regular sized version with cv2.drawContours

When I use the following code to resize it I end up with [this here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV2Qa.png) before and after.

```
M = cv2.moments(cnt)
cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

cnt_norm = cnt - [cx, cy]
cnt_scaled = cnt_norm * scale
cnt_scaled = cnt_scaled + [cx, cy]
cnt_scaled = cnt_scaled.astype(np.int32)
```

As you can see its not quite symmetrical on the top and bottom due to the skew, how can I fix this?

Comment: can You paste the full code, like how you get ```cnt```. And the original image?

Comment: "not quite symmetrical"? looks symmetrical to me. optical illusion?

Comment: @crackanddie The `cnt` is just hard coded those 4 points to form that shape.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz The bottom and top are longer than the sides.

Comment: that's easy... you **scaled** the thing. what you see is what *must* happen when you scale it. -- what you (appear to) want is a contour that is *offset* by a fixed distance.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz How can I achieve that ?

Comment: morphology operations, if you have a mask. you probably do, or else you wouldn't have a contour.